# Hide a image behind a border in html, css

Tags: html, css

I wish to hide a video behind a border and appreciate any help I can get. This is what I have now with the image above the border.

```
<div style="padding:20px;background-color:#000000;border:15px outset #b9b9b9;font-family:courier;">

<iframe width="550" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/S_UTUXDs-tE?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: what do you mean hide?

Comment: please elaborate what is the context of what you are trying to do

Comment: I want the song to play without the video visible.

Comment: oh that's against YouTube TOS 5.G "if you use the YouTube Player on your website may not modify, build upon or block any portion or functionality of the YouTube Player including but not limited to links back to the Website;" https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms

Comment: just to give you an advice, instead of doing that, use <audio> tag and use an MP3 version of that song. saves so much bandwidth

Answer (score 1):

try this give iframe width 100% and wrap it inside div like this

```
<div style="padding:20px;background-color:#000000;border:15px outset #b9b9b9;font-family:courier;">

<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/S_UTUXDs-tE?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add to div style:

```
style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:550px;height:315;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you try to do is allowed by youtube.
but you can just say this on the iframe:

```
style="visibility=hidden;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it violates the Youtube Terms of Service, just to answer how to do it for the sake of knowledge

This will be your HTML

```
<div style="padding:20px;background-color:#000000;border:15px outset #b9b9b9;font-family:courier;" class="yt-vid">

<iframe width="550" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/S_UTUXDs-tE?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

in your CSS

```
.yt-vid > iframe {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I do not encourage you to do this. You should not do this actually.

Comment: I will not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style="visibility: hidden;"` css tag in iframe. Or just give 0 (zero) width to `iframe`.